# How could i put these specific array items into list?

Tags: c#

So i have a problem with my homework I have to put the performer of the songs(Eric Clapton,Omega,etc.) into generic lists.The words are from a file it looks like this line by line:

1 5 3 Deep Purple:Bad Attitude
2 3 36 Eric Clapton:Terraplane Blues
3 2 46 Eric Clapton:Crazy Country Hop
3 3 25 Omega:Ablakok
2 4 23 Eric Clapton:Catch Me If You Can
1 3 27 Eric Clapton:Willie And The Hand Jive
3 4 33 Omega:A szamuzott
2 6 20 Eric Clapton:Old love

the problem is that if i load a line into a string and split it the performers aren't always at the same index how could i load the performers into a list?

Comment: You'll need to do multiple splits or use regex.

Comment: In addition to @DarrenYoung: check out https://www.dotnetperls.com/split. You will need to split for spaces, dots and colons I think

Comment: We can´t say you how to do this because we have no idea on the specifics of your file-structure. When you say there are scenarious in which the index of the performers name is different than what you expect how should we know? This question isn´t solvable without a clear idea on your file-structure and in particular your current code showing your atemps so far.

Comment: so you just need to have the performers in the list? not the songs or preceding information?

Comment: I am not sure why you put this on hold, the question was clear, he needs to be able to extract the artist names from the list.

Answer (score 1):

you would want a regex that looks something like this:
\d+ \d+ \d+([^:]+)
That should give you the artist name based on your list.  If you need a tool to test your regex, [this site](https://regex101.com/) works great.

Comment: I would also like to add, that if you have a long string (a file that has been read into a single string), regex can give you a collection of all captured groups within that string.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
        string txt = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("myfile.txt");
        List<string> lines = txt.Split(System.Environment.NewLine.ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToList();
        foreach (string line in lines)
        {
            string name = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(line, @"[\d-]", string.Empty).Trim();
        }
```